# How to add custom class to ckeditor uploaded image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ckeditor, wysiwyg

in ckeditor image is not responsive, after uploading image it is showing on full width and existing style of my site changing.By default below is taking.

```
<img alt="" height="someheight" src="http://www.someweb.com/file_name4.gif" width="somewidth" />
```

I want to add custom class to this block after uploading image.As shown below.

```
<img class="someclass" alt=""  height="somewidth" src="http://www.someweb.com/file_name4.gif" width="somewidth" />
```